# Smarty Template CMS-agnostic URL

Tags: smarty

Please can someone remind me how to create a CMS-safe URL in Smarty Templates?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

{crmURL p="civicrm/points/grant" q="cid=$cid&type=$type"}

^this

The p is the address of the page
The q is the list of parameters
The domain is added first

So the above code (with $cid=A and $type=B) translates into:

http://example.org/civicrm/points/grant?cid=A&type=B

Comment: Hi John, this looks like it could be useful to others.  Could you edit your answer to say a bit more and explain what the different parameters mean?  I think that could make it even more helpful.